# Javascript/HTML: Close Dropdown Text

Tags: javascript

so I created a small HTML and Javascript Code, in which I want to build a dropdown and dropup text field. When you click one of the three questions, the answer pops up using OnClick and I had it working. But now I decided to add multiple  to one , which works fine to the point where it drops down, but whatever I do, it won't drop back in and disappear again. I'm sure I'm making a stupid mistake at this point, but I can't help myself any more. How can I get it to disappear again?

The Code can be found here: http://cdpn.io/vdcDq

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You say:

```
if (element_dd.style.display = 'none')
  element_dd.style.display = 'block';
else
  element_dd.style.display = 'none';
```

(note the `=` where you mean `==`)

This always sets `display` to `none`, the condition is always `true`, so `display` is immediately set to `block`.

Also, the first time through, `display` may actually be *empty* instead of `none`.  Try:

```
if ((element_dd.style.display == 'none') || ! element_dd.style.display)
  element_dd.style.display = 'block';
else
  element_dd.style.display = 'none';
```

Working example: http://cdpn.io/JDsIo

Comment: Thank you very much! I can't believe I didn't see this myself.